# Stone–Čech Compactification of $\mathbb{Z}$ with Fürstenberg Topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, ultrafilters, stone-cech-compactification

The Stone–Čech Compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ as a discrete space has been extensively studied and can be [represented using ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification).

Consider $X=(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the Fürstenberg topology generated by arithmetic sequences. Equipped with this [exotic topology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0713v1), $X$ is a topological ring, metrizable, and totally disconnected.

Since $X$ is metrizable, it is Tychonoff and the map from $X$ to its image in $\beta X$ (its compactification) is a homeomorphism.

Has $\beta X$ been studied? Is there a straightforward description analogous to the compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology?

Comment: The Fürstenberg topology is just the profinite topology, by the way. It's not so exotic. (That means that one compactification is the profinite completion $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. I don't know if this is the Stone-Čech compactification.) 

Comment: I also wouldn't call the description of $\beta \mathbb{N}$ in terms of ultrafilters straightforward. From a certain perspective it's more or less a tautology (namely the perspective where a compact Hausdorff space is an algebra over the ultrafilter monad); you're not really learning much more than you already knew when you just knew that Stone-Čech compactifications existed. 

Comment: @Qiaochu: really? What about Ramsey-theoretic applications?

Comment: Also, isn't the profinite completion going to be a group (which Stone-Cech isn't)?

Comment: There is a paper by I. Glicksberg which discusses when the Stone-Cech-compactification preserves products. If this works here, $\beta \mathbb{Z}$ is a topological ring since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a topological ring.

Comment: The dense embedding $\mathbb{Z} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ induces a surjective continuous map $\beta \mathbb{Z} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. Is it also injective?

Comment: Martin, yes. See my comment to Joseph's answer.

Comment: @Francois, see Joseph van Name's cardinality argument

Comment: @Jackson: I think that you are identifying the Furstenberg/profinite compactification with the Stone-Cech and they are **not the same**

Comment: @Yemen No, no, that was what I was trying to avoid, my notation was just confusing.

Comment: I'm just joining the conversation here and I must say that I am very confused since it appears that the notation $\beta \mathbb Z$ is being used by some to denote the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb Z$ with the discrete topology, and by others to denote the Stone-Cech compactification with respect to the topology $\mathcal T$. Perhaps writing $\beta (\mathbb Z, \mathcal T)$ to denote the latter would help?

Comment: @Jackson (and others): oops, my misreading. Apologies for generating or prolonging any confusion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can also describe $\beta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ in terms of ultrafilters on Boolean algebras. I claim that $\beta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ is the space of ultrafilters on the Boolean algebra of clopen sets in $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ where $\mathcal{T}$ is the Fürstenberg topology.

Recall that a space $X$ is zero-dimensional if it has a basis of clopen sets, and recall that a zero set on a space $X$ is a set of the form $f^{-1}(0)$ for some continuous $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. A completely regular space $X$ is said to be strongly zero-dimensional if the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$ is zero-dimensional. It can be shown that a completely regular space $X$ is strongly zero-dimensional if and only if whenever $Z_{1},Z_{2}\subseteq X$ are disjoint zero sets, there is a clopen set $C\subseteq X$ with $Z_{1}\subseteq C,Z_{2}\subseteq C^{c}$ [1 p. 85]. In other words, a completely regular space is strongly zero-dimensional iff every pair of zero sets is separated by a clopen set. If $X$ is zero-dimensional, then let $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ denote the Boolean algebra of clopen subsets of $X$ and let $\zeta X$ be the space of ultrafilters on $\mathfrak{B}(X)$. Then $\zeta X$ is in a sense the maximal zero-dimensional compactification of $X$ which is called the Banaschewski compactification. If $X$ is strongly zero-dimensional, then the Banaschewski compactification $\zeta X$ is precisely the Stone-Čech compactification. In [1. p. 86] it states that zero-dimensionality and strong zero-dimensionality are equivalent in Lindelöf spaces. Therefore since $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ is zero-dimensional and Lindelöf, the space $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ is strongly zero-dimensional. We conclude that $\beta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})=\zeta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ is the space of ultrafilters on $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$.

In order to clear up some confusion about the space $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ and its Stone-Čech compactification, I will outline some basic facts about $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ and $\beta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$.

I claim that the space $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ has an infinite partition into clopen sets. It is not too hard to give an explicit example of such a partition. For a more slick proof, assume that $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ has no partition into countably many clopen sets. If $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{Z}$, then there is a clopen cover $\{C_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ that refines $\mathcal{U}$. If we set $D_{n}=C_{n}\setminus(C_{0}\cup...\cup C_{n-1})$ for all $n$, then $\{D_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a partition of $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ into finitely many clopen sets that refines $\mathcal{U}$, so $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ is compact. This is a contradiction. Therefore $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ has a partition into countably many clopen sets.

In particular, there is a continuous surjective function $f:(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ where $\mathbb{N}$ has the discrete topology. Therefore the map $f$ extends to a continuous surjective function $\bar{f}:\beta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})\rightarrow\beta\mathbb{N}$. Since $|\beta\mathbb{N}|=2^{\mathbb{c}}$, we conclude that $|\beta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})|=2^{\mathbb{c}}$ as well. We conclude that the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ is much larger than the pro-finite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$.

[1] The Stone-Čech Compactification, Russell Walker (1970)

Comment: Excellent! Incidentally, I think this shows that $\beta\mathbb{Z}$ is $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ since (if my computations are correct) the clopen sets in the Fürstenberg topology are precisely the finite unions of arithmetic progressions. Thus, an ultrafilter $p$ on the clopen algebra is such that there is exactly one arithmetic progression $a_p(N) + \mathbb{Z}N \in p$ for each modulus $N$. These must be coherent and thus determine a point $\hat{p} \in \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. The map $p \mapsto \hat{p}$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: ... because the arithmetic progressions are dense in the clopen algebra. So the clopen sets that contain the arithmetic progressions $q + \mathbb{Z}N$ where $q \equiv \hat{p} \pmod{N}$ form an ultrafilter, which has to be $p$.

Comment: That's great!  But can we please stop calling it the Furstenberg topology?

Comment: You have a point there, but what should we do with all the things named after Abel, Tauber, Diophantus, Euclid, Ramsey, etc. that have even less to do with these people? Naming something after the inventor is typical but it's not a strict rule...

Comment: @Francois, as I commented above, I don't see how beta Z can be the profinite completion if the profinite competion is a group. See the discussion I linked to in my comment

Comment: I think there is an infinite partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ into clopen sets. If not, then $\mathbb{Z}$ would be pseudocompact by my old question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103543/is-every-zero-dimensional-space-with-no-infinite-clopen-partition-pseudocompact. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}$ would be compact since it is realcompact and pseudocompact. This is a contradiction. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}$ has an infinite partition into clopen sets.

Comment: Also, I think I have an explicit example of an infinite partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ into clopen sets.

Comment: That Boolean algebra homomorphism is not an isomorphism since it is not surjective. There are clopen sets in $\mathbb{Z}$ that do not correspond to clopen sets in $\hat{Z}$.

Comment: Francois, in this case, there's already a perfectly good, universally accepted, name - the profinite topology.

Comment: The word profinite is also much more pleasant to pronounce than the name Furstenberg and it describes what the topology looks like.

Comment: One can write down an infinite partition into clopen subsets using the ultrametric on $\mathbb{Z}$ constructed in the paper mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Joseph, sorry you are right.  My brain is not functioning today.  I was conflating recognizable sets with clopen sets in the profinite topology but they are not the same.  You are right.  The profinite topology on the free monoid is discrete so all sets are clopen.  But only the regular languages correspond to clopens in the free profinite semigroup. Sorry!  



Comment: I deleted my nonsense comments and gave a +1.  Need more sleep :(

Comment: This is great! I had just found a note where I wrote down an example of an infinite clopen partition of $\mathbb{Z}$, but now I see that Joseph already corrected my mistake. It was still a funny feeling to see that I had preemptively proven myself wrong... By the way, an easy one consists of $3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pm1+6\mathbb{Z}$,$\pm2+12\mathbb{Z}$,$\pm4+24\mathbb{Z}$,...

Comment: @Francois, you had me convinced for a long while, but Joseph persevered.  Great answer!

Comment: Henry, I know it is also the profinite topology but I don't see why it can't be called the Fürstenberg topology too. There are plenty of things that have two names.


Comment: There isn't a problem with a thing having multiple names, but it can be an issue if multiple things have the same name. For any subset $S$ of the primes, $\prod_{p \in S} \mathbb{Z}_p$ is profinite, and the diagonal embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ inherits a different topology for each subset. So there are uncountably many "profinite" topologies on $\mathbb{Z}$, and it's more reasonable to single out one of them as "the Furstenberg topology" than to refer to any particular one as "the profinite topology".

Answer (score 8):

Topologically speaking $\mathbb{Z}$ with the topology mentioned above is just (homeomorphic to) the space of rational numbers. The space $\beta\mathbb{Q}$ has been studied a lot (not as much as $\beta\mathbb{N}$), for example by Eric van Douwen in *Remote Points* [(MR link)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=627526), freely available [here at DMLPL](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.zamlynska-334f9e04-e784-4a82-8eb3-b9605ad33a80).

Comment: By the way from this point of view it's immediate that it has uncountably many clopen subsets and hence so does the Stone-Čech compactification, which is therefore not metrizable. Namely, for every $\{1,2\}$-valued sequence $u$, the union $V_u=\bigcup_n [3n,3n+u_n]\smallsetminus\mathbf{Q}$ is clopen in $\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{Q}$, and $u\mapsto V_u$ is injective.

Comment: Could you remind us why $\mathbb{Z}$ with the arithmetic-sequence = Fürstenberg topology is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology?

Comment: See this paper by Sierpinski: https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-1-1-11-16  Every countable dense-in-itself metrizable space is homeomorphic to the space of rationals.

Comment: Or see this paper in The American Mathematical Monthly of May, 2019: https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2019.1577103

Answer (score 0):

**Edit.** The comments and the other answers reveal that my proof has some gap. But I won't delete it, instead I've rewritten it as an *attempt* to prove $\beta \mathbb{Z} = \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. I hope that the failure of this naive proof motivates to read the more sophisticated answers.

---

When $\mathbb{Z}$ is equipped with the Fürstenberg topology, do we have $\beta \mathbb{Z} = \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$?

The Fürstenberg topology is the subspace topology induced by the profinite completion $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} = \lim_{n>0} \mathbb{Z}/n$. The embedding $\mathbb{Z} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is dense, hence for every compact Hausdorff space $X$ we get an injective map $\hom(\hat{\mathbb{Z}},X) \to \hom(\mathbb{Z},X)$. The question is whether it is surjective, because this would mean that $ \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ satisfies the defining universal property of $\beta \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \to X$ be a continuous map. This means that for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, every open subset $U \subseteq X$ containing $f(a)$ already contains $f(a+n \mathbb{Z})$ for some $n>0$. Let $a=(a_1,a_2,\dotsc) \in \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, i.e. $a_n \equiv a_m \bmod n$ for $n|m$. Since $X$ is compact, the net $(f(a_n))_{n>0}$ (using divisibility for the indices) has a convergent subnet, say $(f(a_{n(i)}))_{i \in I} \longrightarrow x$.

Actually any two subnets have the same limit: Assume that $(f(a_{m(j)}))_{j \in J} \longrightarrow y$. Choose open neighborhoods $U,V$ of $x,y$, it is enough to prove $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ since $X$ is Hausdorff. For large $i$ we have that $f(a_{n(i)}) \in U$, and for large $j$ we have $f(a_{m(j)}) \in V$. Choose $b>0$ with $f(a_{n(i)} + b \mathbb{Z}) \subseteq U$ and $f(a_{m(j)} + b \mathbb{Z}) \subseteq V$. We may assume $n(i),m(j)|b$. For $p=n(i) m(j)$ we have $a_p \equiv a_{n(i)} \bmod n(i)$, hence $a_p \equiv a_{n(i)} \bmod b$. Similarily we get $a_p \equiv a_{m(j)} \bmod b$. Hence $f(a_p) \in U \cap V$.

Hence $\tilde{f}(a) := $(the limit of some subnet of $f(a_n)$) gives a well-defined map $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} \to X$. Clearly it agrees with $f$ on constant sequences. But now the problem seems to be that $\tilde{f}$ is not continuous ...

Comment: $|\beta\mathbb{Z}|=2^{2^{\aleph_{0}}}$ and clearly $|\hat{\mathbb{Z}}|$ has cardinality continuum.

Comment: Martin, doesn't your argument only work if when "let $f: Z \to X$ be continuous" you are equipping Z with the subspace topology from its profinite completion, hence you're just showing that a continuous function on a dense subset had a unique continuous extension? (You don't use compactness of range)

Comment: (OK, you do use compactness of range - wish I could edit comments! - but my first point still stands)

Comment: The problem is that subnets are terrible to work with. Subnets should be avoided whenever possible. I have never found a legitimate use for subnets. 

Comment: I think you all refer to $\beta \mathbb{Z}$ when $\mathbb{Z}$ is equipped with the discrete topology. But of course here it is equipped with the Fürstenberg topology, as in the question.

Comment: And besides, where do you think is an error in my proof? Are the downvotes really justified?

Comment: I was not talking about $\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology. Your proof gives an erroneous result, so it is not correct.

Comment: So where is the error? And is there really a general formula for the cardinality of the Stone-Cech compactification for non-discrete spaces?

Comment: Since there is an infinite partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ into clopen sets there is a surjective continuous function $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. This map extends to a continuous surjective map $\overline{f}:\beta\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\beta\mathbb{N}$, so $|\beta\mathbb{Z}|=2^{2^{\aleph_{0}}}$.